# How to write code below as jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I write the code below as a jquery:

```
var imagefile = document.getElementsByClassName("fileImage");
var filename = imagefile.files[0];
```

I attempted this below but it says it is not defined even though I have already stated file input's class is 'fileImage'.

```
var filename = $('.fileImage').files[0];
```

Comment: @dan_l: array-like, technically.

Answer (score 4):

you can't directly do `imagefile.files[0]` since

```
document.getElementsByClassName("fileImage")
//and
$('.fileImage')
```

return an "array-like" list of items. (AFAIK, `getElementsBy*` functions, except for `getElementsById`, return a `NodeList`)

you need to iterate through them first, before you get `files[0]`.

for the pure JS approach:

```
for(var i=0; i < imagefile.length;i++){
    var imgfile = imagefile[i];

    //now imgfile is the DOM element itself
    imgfile.files[0];
}
```

for the jQuery, you chain `.each()`

```
$('.fileImage').each(function(){

   //"this" in here is the DOM element

   this.files[0];

})
```

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery object returned by the $() function doesn't have a .files property - that property belongs to the DOM element. Try this:

```
var filename = $('.fileImage')[0].files[0];
```

This will still give an error if no elements match the selector, otherwise it uses the square-bracket array syntax on the jQuery object to get a reference to the first matching element.

If you want to test if any elements matched the selector use the jQuery objects .length property:

```
var $files = $('.fileImage'),
    filename;
if ($files.length > 0) {
   filename = $files[0].files[0];
   // do something with filename...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `.files[]` is not part of jQuery.